# Input redirection in test1 > test2 < test3

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

I am trying to understand how input redirection works so that I can simulate it in a shell I am building. Let's say we create 3 files:

```
echo this is test 1 > test1
echo this is test 2 > test2
echo this is test 3 > test3
```

And then we try to redirect input and output using a command like `cat test1 > test2 < test 3`.
The contents of test2 will become: `this is a test1`. I would expect them to become `this is a test 3` since this is the last "operation". What am I getting wrong? Thank you in advance!

PS If you can *direct* me to a guide on how redirection works when having complicated commands like the one above I would be grateful!

Comment: `cat` does not read from stdin when it has non-option arguments.  (Unless one of those arguments specifies stdin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` does not read from stdin when it has non-option arguments unless one of those arguments specifies stdin.  In the example you provided, `cat test1 > test2 < test3`, the file `test3` is the input stream for `cat`, but `cat` is ignoring it because you didn't specify `-` as an argument.  If you instead do `cat test1 - > test2 < test3`, then `cat` will read its stdin, but the final content of `test2` will not merely be the content of `test3`, but the concatenation of `test1` and `test3`.

Perhaps you should try the experiments:

```
cat test1 - > test2 < test3
cat > test2 < test3
cat - test1 - > test2 < test3
cat - - test1 test1 > test2 < test3
```

Also, perhaps look at

```
< test3 cat > test2
cat < test3 - test1 > test2
```

Comment: Thank you, the examples really helped me!